# Lambda capture QFile object

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, lambda

I want to maintain a file inside of a lambda function. I'm able to work on it outside of a lambda, but as soon as I pass it as a reference and want to check for its existence after downloading it, my application is crashing on this line: `if (workFile.exists() && !workFile.remove()) {`.

```
QFile workFile("path/to/file.bat");

[..]

if (!workFile.exists()) {
    [..] download file & such
    QObject::connect(&mng, &FileManager::onDownload, this, [=, &workFile] (const QString& name) {
        if (workFile.exists() && !workFile.remove()) {
            qDebug() << "File was not downloaded correctly.";
        }
    });
}
```

Backtrace:

[image]

Why is it not working? How I am supposed to capture the QFile correctly?

Comment: @Mike Good catch, post it as an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When capturing an object by reference, if the lambda is invoked after the object's lifetime has ended, you get a dangling reference. You should always ensure that objects passed by reference are still valid when the lambda is invoked.

In your example, the `QFile` object goes out of scope before the lambda is actually called, this happens because your `FileManager` emits `onDownload` after your function has finished, the lambda gets a reference to an invalid object, and you get a crash.

You can solve this by instantiating another `QFile` instance with the same filename inside the lambda (instead of capturing the old one), or use the static alternatives (if you just want to check for existence and remove): [`QFile::exists()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#exists), [`QFile::remove()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#remove-1).

If you really need to capture the old `QFile` instance, you have to ensure that its lifetime is valid when the lambda is invoked (you may do that by allocating it on the heap using `new` and `delete`ing it yourself when you are finished).